# How to set the SessionID while creating the Session in Java Rest API

Tags: java, rest, httprequest, session-cookies, jsessionid

My objective to create a session in java with the JSESSIONID I am passing in the request cookie so that when I send the request again, then I can use the same session everytime and the new session is not created with new session id.

```
    public ObjectRestResponse<String> storeToken(StoreMobileTokenRequest tokenRequestBody, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ObjectRestResponse<String> response = new ObjectRestResponse<String>();

        System.out.println("SessionIdFromRequest"+request.getCookies());
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        System.out.println("SessionId"+session.getId());

        HashMap<String, String> hmpAttribute  =null;
        if(session.getAttribute("NotificationToken") == null) {
             hmpAttribute = new HashMap<String, String>();  
            hmpAttribute.put(tokenRequestBody.getEmpNo(), tokenRequestBody.getTokenId());

            session.setAttribute("NotificationToken", hmpAttribute);

        }

        else {
            hmpAttribute = (HashMap<String, String>) session.getAttribute("NotificationToken");
            hmpAttribute.put(tokenRequestBody.getEmpNo(), tokenRequestBody.getTokenId());
            session.setAttribute("NotificationToken", hmpAttribute);

        }

        response.setData("Success");
        return response;
    }
```

But for each new request from Rest client, a new session gets created instead of using the old session.

Please tell what am I doing wrong or what do I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Session cookies are created by the *server* and given back to the client, which must then send the session cookie on subsequent requests.

The server may send a new session cookie any time it wants to, and the client must then immediately begin using the updated cookie.

It is never the client that creates the cookie value.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for update. But i have different clients, but they all want to use the same session. So say my first client sends the request to server and the session is created. But i want my 2nd client to use the same session. I checked somewhere that if i pass the fixed JSESSIONID in cookie from each client then i can use the same session .Please tell if its possible.

Comment: @Ashutosh That is session stealing, and should not be done. If you want some high-level "session" for sharing state between multiple clients, then you should implement that yourself, instead of trying to hack the clients Servlet Session.